# date command timezone not reflecting correct date/time from timedatectl

Tags: 20.04, date, ntp

I am in the MDT timezone (UTC -600).  When I run the `date` command it shows the UTC time but shows MDT as the timezone, so the timezone looks correct but the time is actually 6 hours ahead of what it should be.  I have copied the correct timezone to `/etc/localtime` and have updated the correct timezone in `/etc/timezone`

I am trying to figure out why the timezone (MDT) but the time is reflecting the UTC time.

I am running *Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS*.

Here is the information from my system:

**`date` command output:**

```
Mon Sep 13 17:52:06 MDT 2021
```

**`ls -lh /etc/localtime` output:`**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Sep 13 17:40 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Boise
```

**`timedatectl` output:**

```
           Local time: Mon 2021-09-13 11:53:49 MDT
           Universal time: Mon 2021-09-13 17:53:49 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2021-09-13 17:53:49
                Time zone: America/Boise (MDT, -0600)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

**`/etc/timezone` contents:**

```
America/Boise
```

I have tried running `chronyd -Q` to sync the time, etc but I am still showing UTC time with a MDT timezone.

If anyone has any ideas how I can get this to reflect the accurate time and timezone I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for taking the time to look.